# Shell Removing part of a string with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Good day.

I actually have 2 questions that are related to the sed command in shell and they are very similar.

The first question is how to use sed to get a file name and remover part of it's name like the example below:

Original file:

BAT_MAN_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt

What i want the file name to look like:

BAT_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt

I just want the "MAN" part after the first underline to be removed out of the original file  name.

The second question is about the following sed command that I've found on a file a while ago:

```
random_string_var_name=$(echo $file_name | sed -r 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*_t[0-9]{1}).*(_[0-9]*)\.txt/_\1\2/')
```

this pretty much get parts of a file name a saves it on a variable, like the example bellow:

Name of the file:

```
BAT_MAN_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt
```

What that sed command gets:

```
T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345
```

I got what it does but i don't understand how that command works, so i would like to understand that.

Comment: You shouldn't even need `sed` for this... Try `echo ${file_name//MAN_/}`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want the "MAN" part after the first underline to be removed out of the original file name.

```
echo "BAT_MAN_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt" | sed "s/MAN_//"
```

> What if i want to always remove the first word after the first underline and keep everything else?

```
echo "BAT_MAN_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt" | sed -r 's/^([^_]*)_[^_]*(_.*)/\1\2/'
```

> what does this do: `echo $file_name | sed -r 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*_t[0-9]{1}).*(_[0-9]*)\.txt/_\1\2/')`

- `-r`: runs sed in "extended regex" mode
- `^`: matches beginning of word
- `[^_]*` matches everything except underline 0 or more times
- `_` matches underline
- `(.*_t[0-9]{1})` matches zero or more of anything followed by _t and only one number. This match is stored in variable 1
- `(_[0-9]*)` same thing, only that there is no prefix
- `/_\1\2`: replaces the whole filename with _ at the beginning and the match in the first brackets and the match in the second bracket

I recommend reading up on regular expressions. They are important and not *really* hard to get into

Comment: To add: If OP wants to rename the file, they can use [`rename`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) tool.

Comment: out of curiosity, how would i do to use sed to always take that second word of a file name delimited by underlines, because some times the name of the files change and i plan to put this command in a script?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man I don't understand. You mean how would you only match `MAN` in `BAT_MAN_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt`?

Comment: it is because, sometimes, the file names very a bit, instead of being named BAT_MAN_T_etc they are also named like BAT_WOMAN_T_* or GREEN_LANTERN_T_etc. What if i want to always remove the first word after the first underline and keep everything else?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may have something else than "MAN", you may have "WOMAN". So you can use:

```
file_name=BAT_WOMAN_T_spades_proc_whatever_t6_12345_14785963214785_12345.txt
echo $file_name | sed 's/_[^_]*_/_/'
```